# Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares (every prime $p$ s.t. $p \not\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ is a sum of two squares)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups, prime-factorization, sums-of-squares

I'm reflecting the following proof (see below). My question is where it uses the given fact ($p \not\equiv 3 \pmod 4$)? I'm not sure it uses this fact, and it kind of makes me think that something is wrong. Would appriciate your help.

**Draft of a possible partial proof.**
Let $p = 3 \pmod 4$ be a prime number. Assume that $p = a^2 + b^2$. Then $a^2 + b^2 = 0 \pmod p$, implying that $a^2 = -b^2 \pmod p$. By raising both sides in $(p-1)/2$, then using Fermat's little theorem we saw in problem set 6, we conclude that $p \mid 2$.

Comment: The primes that are $\not\equiv 3\bmod 4$ are exactly the ones that are the sum of two squares. It sounds like you have this backwards.

Comment: The title is not correct. Those prime numbers ARE the sum of two perfect squares.

Comment: When $p\equiv1\pmod 4$ your argument gives $1\equiv1\pmod p$.

Comment: The more difficult part is to show that primes of the form $\ 4k+1\ $ are the sum of two perfect squares. That it is impossible for $\ 4k+3\ $ , is almost trivial. And the case $\ p=2\ $ is immediate ($\ 2=1^2+1^2\ $)

Comment: Fixed the title

Comment: "is a" is an implication which is only one-directional. Compared with your draft, you edited the title towards the wrong direction. You are trying to prove that any prime $p\equiv3\pmod4$ can't be the sum of two squares.

Comment: Your draft indeed does not use the fact that $p\not\equiv3\pmod4$, instead it assumes (and uses) that $p\equiv3\pmod4$ when deducting that $(p-1)/2$ is odd to get a contradiction. This would show that if the sum of two squares is a prime $p$, then $p\not\equiv3\pmod4$, but it doesn't help in showing that if $p\not\equiv3\pmod4$ for a prime $p$ then that $p$ is the sum of two squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a typo in the question. If $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, $(p-1)/2$ is a even number so you would get $1 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ which is not a contradiction. Only when $(p-1)/2$ is odd, you would get $ 1 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Every perfect square is congruent to $\ 0\ $ or $\ 1\ $ modulo $\ 4\ $. This can easily be shown by cases. And from this it easily follows that a prime of the form $\ 4k+3\ $ cannot be the sum of two perfect squares.

Comment: A more advanced approach is possible with the theory of quadratic residues : The main idea is to show that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo a prime of the form $4k+3$. Hence , $a^2+b^2 =p$ cannot work for coprime integers $a,b$ , but neither if they are not coprime since then the sum of the two perfect squares cannot be squarefree, in particular not prime.

Answer (score 2):

The question is where are you using the fact that $p\equiv 3\mod 4$. Answer: you are using the fact that $(p-1)/2$ is odd and so

$$(-b^2)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=-1\mod p.$$

That is only true if $p\equiv 3\mod 4$